# Android BluetoothSocket.connect() таймаут

Tags: android, сокет, bluetooth, timeout

Иногда метод  `BluetoothSocket.connect();` не возвращается никогда. То есть вешает поток, на котором запущен на неопределенно долгое время. Я ищу способ, как установить ему таймаут, или попросту прервать его выполнение так, чтобы разблокировать дальнейшую работу с блютусом. Кто-нибудь знает такой способ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BlueToohSocket.close() из другого потока или Thread.stop() уже пробовали?

> public void connect ()
>
> ...
>
> close() can be used to abort this call from another thread.

Comment: действительно... Я так уже пробовал раньше, но впоследствии у меня зависал дивайс с которым я работаю по BT. Из за этого я принял этот метод за не рабочий. Спасибо!